# Microsoft Access: Error Message Row size too large

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am not aware of any restrictions in regard to the row size of my access database, but I am getting following error message when trying to update a record, with more than 10 characters. I am using following SQL command via DBeaver:

```
UPDATE 'amenities' 
SET [Bar Opening Times]="12345678901"
WHERE HostelKey="WOMLON";
```

and receive following error message:

> SQL Error [15000] [15000]: UCAExc:::5.0.1 Row size 4061 is too large (Db=womdb.accdb;Table=amenities)

Detailed Error Code:

> org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [15000] [15000]:
> UCAExc:::5.0.1 Row size 4061 is too large
> (Db=womdb.accdb;Table=amenities)  at
> org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:133)
> at
> org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:509)
> at
> org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$0(SQLQueryJob.java:440)
> at
> org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:168)
> at
> org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:427)
> at
> org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:812)
> at
> org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:3220)
> at
> org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:121)
> at
> org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:168)
> at
> org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:119)
> at
> org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetViewer.java:4516)
> at
> org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
> at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63) Caused
> by: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::5.0.1 Row
> size 4061 is too large (Db=womdb.accdb;Table=amenities)   at
> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.execute(UcanaccessStatement.java:159)
> at
> org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.execute(JDBCStatementImpl.java:327)
> at
> org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:130)
> ... 12 more Caused by: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException:
> UCAExc:::5.0.1 Row size 4061 is too large
> (Db=womdb.accdb;Table=amenities)  at
> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.commit(UcanaccessConnection.java:212)
> at
> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.AbstractExecute.executeBase(AbstractExecute.java:273)
> at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.Execute.execute(Execute.java:44)     at
> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.execute(UcanaccessStatement.java:157)
> ... 14 more Caused by: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException:
> UCAExc:::5.0.1 Row size 4061 is too large
> (Db=womdb.accdb;Table=amenities)  at
> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.flushIO(UcanaccessConnection.java:360)
> at
> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.commit(UcanaccessConnection.java:205)
> ... 17 more Caused by: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException:
> UCAExc:::5.0.1 Row size 4061 is too large
> (Db=womdb.accdb;Table=amenities)  at
> net.ucanaccess.commands.CompositeCommand.persist(CompositeCommand.java:96)
> at
> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.flushIO(UcanaccessConnection.java:323)
> ... 18 more Caused by:
> com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.InvalidValueException: Row size 4061
> is too large (Db=womdb.accdb;Table=amenities)     at
> com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TableImpl.updateRow(TableImpl.java:2549)
> at
> com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.CursorImpl.updateCurrentRow(CursorImpl.java:286)
> at
> net.ucanaccess.commands.UpdateCommand.persist(UpdateCommand.java:192)
> at
> net.ucanaccess.commands.UpdateCommand.persistCurrentRow(UpdateCommand.java:125)
> at
> net.ucanaccess.commands.CompositeCommand.persist(CompositeCommand.java:87)
> ... 19 more

How can I prevent this error?
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c. "4000 : Number of characters in a record (excluding Long Text and OLE Object fields) when the UnicodeCompression property of the fields is set to Yes"

Answer (score 3):

The Access Database Engine stores row data on disk in 4KB pages. A row cannot span more than one page, so the size of the actual data in that row cannot exceed 4000 bytes. We can define a table whose maximum capacity is greater than 4000 bytes, such as this table whose maximum theoretical length is 20 * 255 = 5100 characters

```sql
CREATE TABLE row_length (
txt01 TEXT(255),
txt02 TEXT(255),
txt03 TEXT(255),
txt04 TEXT(255),
txt05 TEXT(255),
txt06 TEXT(255),
txt07 TEXT(255),
txt08 TEXT(255),
txt09 TEXT(255),
txt10 TEXT(255),
txt11 TEXT(255),
txt12 TEXT(255),
txt13 TEXT(255),
txt14 TEXT(255),
txt15 TEXT(255),
txt16 TEXT(255),
txt17 TEXT(255),
txt18 TEXT(255),
txt19 TEXT(255),
txt20 TEXT(255))
```

and we can insert rows whose actual size does not exceed 4000 bytes (in this case, 2000 characters, since a Unicode character may require 2 bytes)

```vb
Sub so67077855()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset("row_length", dbOpenTable)
    Const string_length = 100
    Dim i As Long
    rst.AddNew
    For i = 1 To 20
        Dim field_name As String
        field_name = "txt" & Format(i, "00")
        rst.Fields(field_name).Value = String(string_length, "x")
    Next
    rst.Update
End Sub
```

but if we change the length of each string to `Const string_length = 101` and try to run the code we get

> Run-time error '3047': Record is too large.

Note that "Long Text" (a.k.a. "Memo") fields can be longer than 2000 characters because the record only contains a pointer to the text (in another structure), not the text itself.